# Grails 3 install-templates only creates a scaffolding directory - no artifacts directory

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

The main templates I want to modify are the artifacts ones.  Anyone knows how to create the artifacts templates?

In addition, it only installed these three files in the scaffolding directory:
AsyncController.groovy, AsyncSpec.groovy, ScaffoldedController.groovy.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there is a problem with the install-template command. In  Grails version 3.1 it doesn't create the artifact directory with the views pages (gsp) as expected.

You just have to create an artifact directory and put your customized view pages in it:

```
/$YOUR_GRAIL_APP_DIR/src/main/templates/artifacts/scaffolding/create.gsp
/$YOUR_GRAIL_APP_DIR/src/main/templates/artifacts/scaffolding/edit.gsp
/$YOUR_GRAIL_APP_DIR/src/main/templates/artifacts/scaffolding/index.gsp
/$YOUR_GRAIL_APP_DIR/src/main/templates/artifacts/scaffolding/show.gsp
```

Regards,

-- Sylvio

Comment: Even after adding these they are ignored by grails generate-all or generate-views.  The solution was to go back to scaffolding 3.1.3 and Grails 3.0.9.  That works for both install-templates and generate-*.

Comment: @ChrisMalan - even using Garils 3.0.9, it creates only scafiolding forlder (main/templates/scaffolding). It does not create artifacts.